# Unable to run JUnit5 tests with Bazel inside Docker container

Tags: docker, kotlin, junit, bazel

I have a Kotlin project with Bazel with some JUnit5 tests that I run with:

```
bazel run //my_service:tests
```

and this is the output:

```
Test run finished after 1195 ms
[         3 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         3 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         3 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         5 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         5 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         5 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

5 tests successful. So far, so good. But when tests are run inside Bazel Docker container, I get this output:

```
 Test run finished after 79 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

As you see, no tests are found. Why?

I run tests inside container with these commands:

```
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/my_service --entrypoint "" l.gcr.io/google/bazel:2.2.0 /bin/bash
$ cd my_service
$ bazel run //my_service:tests
```

I'm using Bazel 2.2.0 in both, local and Docker image. Why am I not getting the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. That was really weird. I was using `register_toolchains` rule, instead of `kt_register_toolchain`. Silly me.

Comment: I have been trying to get bzael to work with java/junit5 with no luck.